# English labels for place names (Esri vector tiles)

Tags: esri, vector-tiles

Is there a way to get an Esri ArcGIS map to show place names in English instead of the local language? Here's an example of how Japan looks:

[image]

This is from Esri's [OpenStreetMap_GCS_v2](https://mav7vi0zntdf8xtq.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0a24e94a70934c6f8224f77bd1edeed4) vector tile layer.

Do the vector tiles contain english names, or is there a way to configure this, or does Esri have a different tile layer with English names? Or if the vector tiles do contain the english labels, how do I modify the style to render the English labels?

I did find [World Terrain Reference (WGS84)](https://mav7vi0zntdf8xtq.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6acfb7ac4acf47058acf2dfadd6ea1d7) which has English place names, but it lacks some OSM details like POIs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to configure that, but yes there are other Esri basemaps that have English labels.  For "more details", maybe try the "Navigation" ones as they tend to be more focused on street navigation and have more details.  More in some countries than others. Depending on which projection, and whether you want dark/light, maybe look at the list at
https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/en/browse/#d=3&q=%22Navigation%22&cont=true

Comment: So there's no way to show English labels on the OpenStreetMap_GCS_v2 tile set... The "navigation" layers you mention all use the World_Basemap_GCS_v2 tileset, which isn't really OSM, isn't up to date, and doesn't have a great way to distinguish english from non-english labels... it looks like there are no great options here.

Comment: @Matthias, Since there is no "great" options, what are your priorities? Using esri tiles, using osm data, or just showing "English" labels?   With "English" labels do you mean latin alphabets or actual English names (for example "Copenhagen" vs "København")?

Comment: we have an EPSG:4326 map and ESRI is one of the only providers of that projection. We'd like to show OSM data and label with the `name:en` tag if present, and `name` if not.

Comment: @ Bjorn, I noticed you're Lead Product Engineer at Esri. I wonder if you agree that Esri vector tiles should contain `name:en` data? Having i18l names is ok for local maps, but a worldwide map shows multiple languages (english, arabic, russian, ethiopian, indian, asian, etc.) The problem is no one person can read all of them, so _no one_ can read the full map. If all labels were in a "lingua franca" like English, then at least english speakers could read the full map. Do you see the issue?

Comment: I also asked about this in the forums: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/osm-with-english-labels/td-p/1121403